# why do i need to call the __init__ method of a parent class when initializing new atrributes?

Tags: python, class, methods, attributeerror, init

New programmer here, and I'm just wondering why I need to call the `__init__` method of a parent class in my subclass, if I'm not touching any of the arguments in the first `__init__` method. Isn't the whole point of Method Resolution Order, that the parent class will be called after the subclass in the Method Resolution Order, if a certain method isn't in the subclass.

fx. If I have an instance of a class with the first and last name arguments. but then in a subclass I add an email, and decide to just write an `__init__` method for the email, and then print the first name. shouldn't Python after checking the subclass then check the parent class to see if the "first name" attribute is in an `__init__` method there, instead of giving me an `AttributeError`.

Comment: "shouldn't Python after checking the subclass then check the parent class to see if the "first name" attribute is in an init method there, instead of giving me an attribute error" no, of course not. Python doesn't "check `__init__` methods". It *runs* the method it first encounters in the method resolution order. That's the *whole point of inheritance*

Comment: " Isn't the whole point of Method resolution order, that the parent class will be called after the subclass in the Method Resolution Order, if a certain method isn't in the subclass." A method is only called if it isn't overridden in the resolution order.

Comment: If you have a subclass that only takes the email, but the parent class requires a first and last name, where do you expect the first and last name to come from when you construct an instance of the subclass?  A code example to illustrate what you're talking about might help.

Comment: What you are trying to do is method overloading, but python does not support method overloding, there is a way around by passing `*args` but even then you would have to call the parent init method. resolution order is resolves the init method at the sub class and throws an error when number of parameters dont match.

Answer (score 3):

The method resolution operator is only relevant to attribute *lookup*.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, *, first, last, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.first = first
        self.last = last


class PersonWithEmail:
    def __init__(self, *, email, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.email = email


p = Person(first="John", last="Doe", email="jdoe@example.com")
```

When we call `Person`, we reach a point where we need to call `Person.__init__`. Since `Person.__init__` is defined, we call it, and once it returns, we're done. Only if `Person.__init__` is *not* defined does the MRO come into play, to find an ancestor of `Person` that *does* define an `__init__` method that we can use.

Inside `Person.__init__`, we just call the code that's found. No implicit call to any inherited `__init__` method is made. `super().__init__` finds the *next* class in the MRO with an `__init__` method defined and calls it. Only when all classes in the MRO are using `super` in overriden methods do we *cooperatively* ensure that each appropriate method gets called eventually.

If `PersonWithEmail` does not call `super().__init__`, then the `first` and `last` attribute never get defined, and the instance remains incorrectly initialized. As to whether the decision to not call a parent `__init__` automatically was a good one, that's something you can debate. I will, however, point out that doing so would make `__init__` special in a way that it otherwise is not. It's a method like any other, and you can choose to completely override a parent's `__init__` if you really want to. Also, Python's class system has evolved slightly from its early days, and things you might have done back then aren't things you would want to do now, but changing the rule about no implicit parent calls would be a compatibility-breaking change that was never deemed necessary.